# Can't refer to base-class member in derived template class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

```
template <class T>class Array
{
protected :
    T* data;
    int size;
};
template<class T>class Stack : protected Array<T>
{
    int top;
public:
    Stack(){};

public:
    void Push(T x) {data[++top] = x;}
};
```

Why it say '"data" was not declared in this scope' in `Push`? How can I fix this? When I delete each `template<T>`, it works normally. Is something wrong in my template?

Answer (score 7):

You need:

```
template <class T>class Array
{
protected :
    T* data;
    int size;
};
template<class T>class Stack : protected Array<T>
{
    int top;
public:
    Stack(){};

public:
    // void Push(T x) {data[++top] = x;} <-- Won't compile
    void Push(T x) {this->data[++top] = x;}  // <-- Will compile
    // void Push(T x) {Array<T>::data[++top] = x;} <-- Will also compile
};
```

Because within the implementation of a class template derived from a class template,
members of the base template must be referred to via the this pointer or
with base-class qualification.

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to @Mike's answer you might consider using *using declaration*:

```
template <class T>class Array
{
protected :
    T* data;
    int size;
};
template<class T>class Stack : protected Array<T>
{
    using Array<T>::data; // <--- HERE
    int top;
public:
    Stack(){};

public:
    void Push(T x) {data[++top] = x;}
};
```

Now `data` becomes available in `Stack` class.